# Rename the [super-mario-brothers] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a [super-mario-brothers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-brothers) tag that seems like it would be used for questions about the *Super Mario Bros.* series.

However, this tag is not used just for that specific series within the *Mario* franchise: There's [a question about *Super Mario Galaxy*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/191255/102999) on it, which, while part of the greater *Mario* franchise, is definitely not a *Super Mario Bros.* game — it is completely different gameplay and location-wise from the 2D *Super Mario Bros* games, other than the general characters. There are questions, such as [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/131854/102999), which are not specific to the small group of *Super Mario Bros.* games.

**This tag should be renamed to [super-mario](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario) or [mario-franchise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mario-franchise), as its current name and tag description are a lot narrower than its actual use is.**

Answer (score 6):

[super-mario-brothers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-brothers) seems just fine as a tag for the franchise and the distinction between that and the proposed new name(s) is so minimal it's hardly worth it. Add to that the tag only has 20 questions and Super Mario Bros. is the core of the franchise I don't think it really matters to rename it, the current naming is fine.

Comment: But the Mario series is **way** larger than just *Super Mario Bros.* There are tons of "main" games that wouldn't fit in that sub-series and many spin-offs like *Mario Kart*.

Comment: @Stormblessed - The *Super Mario Bros.* name is used so commonly that no one is going to confuse the usage and assume the franchise only means the "Bros." entries - and if they did, there'd already be another tag, there isn't.

Answer (score -4):

I think we should rename this tag to [super-mario](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario); *Super Mario Bros.* is just a sub-series of the Super Mario franchise, and there are a ton of spin-offs. The questions aren't at all specific much of the time to this tag, and the name of the whole game series is "Super Mario", according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario). **Super Mario Brothers does not refer to the series as a whole, and therefore is a bad tag name. It's like if we called the [mistborn](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mistborn) tag [the-final-empire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-final-empire); it only refers to a sub-series but is being used to label a larger series.**

Comment: If you're going to go down that route, it's worth pointing out that Super Mario is merely a part of the "[Mario Franchise](https://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_(franchise))" which contains (amongst others, Super Mario and Donkey Kong).